# Docker Push Adding Tags instead of Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, repository, push, aws-ecr

I have a private AWS ECR repository where I am pushing images.

I'm running the following commands to push images,

```
1. docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URL:develop -f ./docker/root/dockerfile .
2. docker push $REPOSITORY_URL:develop
```

This works and I can see a new image in my repository with the right image URI and Tag of develop.

However, when I try to add a new image with a different tag by using

```
1. docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URL:release -f ./docker/root/dockerfile .
2. docker push $REPOSITORY_URL:release
```

In my ECR repositoy I don't see a new image but I see my original image with two tags. The original develop tag and now the release tag.

I would expect since I am defining the `$REPOSITORY_URL:release` tag, as release, that when I run `docker push $REPOSITORY_URL:release` it would push my new image with a new tag, and I would be able to see two images in my ECR repository.

Currently the images are identical for testing purposes. Which I think is what is causing this problem. If I run the above commands with a different image it works as expected.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? For example in production if I had to have identical images used my different tags, they would be able to push and work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is same and you just push with different tag then ECR will check manifest will show it under against the same tag.

[image]
In short, if image digest will same, ECR will consider it the same with a different tag.

[image]

So as your image is the same I will suggest using [retagging image.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-retag.html)

**Retagging an Image**

> With Docker Image Manifest V2 Schema 2 images, you can use the
>   --image-tag option of the put-image command to retag an existing image. You can retag without pulling or pushing the image with Docker.
>   For larger images, this process saves a considerable amount of network
>   bandwidth and time required to retag an image.

Also, there is interesting feature of ECR.

**Image Tag Mutability**

> You can configure a repository to be immutable to prevent image tags
>   from being overwritten. Once the repository is configured for
>   immutable tags, an **ImageTagAlreadyExistsException error** will be
>   returned if you attempt to push an image with a tag that already
>   exists in the repository.

[image-tag-mutability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-tag-mutability.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response Adiii! It is helpful